# Как более рационально опрашивать сервер на наличие новых данных?

Tags: python, парсер, клиент-сервер, telebot

Я пишу бот, который опрашивает сайт https://www.olx.ua/ на наличие новых объявлений в определенной категории. Я опрашиваю ссылку и потом по надобности начинаю парсить определенные данные на этом сайте каждые 55 секунд. Приведу самый простой и банальный пример:

```
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.olx.ua/что-то-там'
while True:
    r = requests.get(url)
    for i in range(56):
        sleep(1)
        print(i, end='\r')
```

Я так предполагаю, что через какое-то время (час/день/несколько дней) я получу ошибку 429 (Too many requests). Вопрос - есть ли какой-то стандартный, более правильный и рациональный способ опрашивать ссылку? Примечание - добавлять исключения и проверять `retry-after` не в счет.

Comment: _"Предполагаю, что получу ошибку 429"_, — почему? Если промежуток между запросами будет достаточно большой, то всё должно быть в порядке. Так оно и делается.

Comment: @nomnoms12, то есть это вполне нормально если я буду делать на интересующий мною сайт ~ 1500-2000 запросов/день? Предположим 1 запрос/минута  = 1440 запросов/день

Comment: Зависит от сайта и его спам-фильтров. У меня есть бот, который опрашивает сторонний сервис раз в минуту (1440 rpd), прекрасно работает на протяжении года.

Comment: А вообще, скорость измеряют в запросах в **секунду** (RPS). Например, ВК API позволяет делать до 20 запросов в секунду. И это считается нормальным для крупного сайта.

Comment: В теории сервер способен обработать сотни и тысячи запросов в секунду.

Comment: @nomnoms12, понял, учту это в своем коде, а про запрос в секунду (rps) - запомню =)

Answer (score 0):

Помимо сна, попробуй добавить ему постоянную работу. Пример-

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```